# Keras interfering with python logging

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, keras

I want to log some python code which loads in a trained keras model. For some reason, (python) logging doesn't not work if the keras `load_model` is imported. But (python) logging works fine if I don't import keras.

This works:

```
import logging

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/my_logs.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def do_stuff():
    logging.info("About to do stuff")
    ... stuff gets done here...
```

This doesn't work

```
import logging
from keras.models import load_model

my_model = load_model("fetch_preprocess/lstm_model.h5")

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/my_logs.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def do_stuff():
    logging.info("About to do stuff")
    pred = my_model.predict(data)
    ... stuff gets done here...
```

By "doesn't work", I mean the `logging` module doesn't

- create a new log file
- write to that file anytime `logging` is called

but no error's are ever thrown. So I find this strange.

I believe Keras / tensorflow is interfering with the logging (as the only change I make to the code is to exclude Keras and then logging works fine).

Is there some way to suppress whatever keras is doing in the background so I can use the python logging?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of the bug in the version `0.7.0` of the package, `abseil` and it has been fixed in its `0.8.0` version, as mentioned in this [Github link](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/issues/99#issuecomment-525390675).

The solution to this problem is to upgrade the version of the package `abseil` to greater than or equal to 0.8.

The sample code that

- creates a new log file and
- writes to that file anytime logging is called

is shown below:

`

```
!pip install --upgrade absl-py

import logging
from keras.models import load_model

my_model = load_model("fetch_preprocess/lstm_model.h5")

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/my_logs.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def do_stuff():
    logging.info("About to do stuff")
    pred = my_model.predict(data)
    ... stuff gets done here...

do_stuff()
```

`
Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned, I also think that `Keras` is simply replacing your logger with its own. You can, however, do the following:

```
import logging as my_logging
from keras.models import load_model

my_model = load_model("fetch_preprocess/lstm_model.h5")

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
my_logging.basicConfig(filename="logs/my_logs.log",
                    level=my_logging.DEBUG,
                    format=LOG_FORMAT)
my_logger = my_logging.getLogger()
```