# Logging python package is not working with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, keras

I wrote a script using python which does a few tasks and in the end using Keras load model and predict.
till now I used "print" to get some info/debug to the console but now I need to use log instead.
it looks like keras package is interfering logging package.
logging doesn't work if the Keras load_model is imported. But (python) logging works fine if I don't import keras.

there is already question about that here:
[Keras interfering with python logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836126/keras-interfering-with-python-logging)

I try to use the answer suggested but it still not working. 
will appreciate any help, Thank you.

please see code below to reproduce:

this works:

```
import logging as my_logging
from datetime import datetime
#from keras.models import load_model


time_f = datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')
save_path = 'C:/folder/'
log = save_path+"automation_log_" + time_f + ".log"
my_logging.basicConfig(level=my_logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5.5s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[my_logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(log)), my_logging.StreamHandler()])

my_logging.warning('Watch out!')
my_logging.info('info test!')
```

this is not:

```
import logging as my_logging
from datetime import datetime
from keras.models import load_model


time_f = datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')
save_path = 'C:/folder/'
log = save_path+"automation_log_" + time_f + ".log"
my_logging.basicConfig(level=my_logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5.5s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[my_logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(log)), my_logging.StreamHandler()])

my_logging.warning('Watch out!')
my_logging.info('info test!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue lies in the version `0.7.0` of the package, `abseil` and it has been fixed in its `0.8.0` version, as mentioned in this [Github link](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/issues/99#issuecomment-525390675).

**In short, the solution to this problem is to upgrade the version of the package `abseil` to greater than or equal to 0.8.**

The code which highlights the issue is shown below:

```
!pip install absl-py==0.7
!pip show absl-py # This outputs 0.7

import logging as my_logging
from datetime import datetime
from keras.models import load_model

time_f = datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')
save_path = 'sample_data'
log = save_path+"automation_log_" + time_f + ".log"
my_logging.basicConfig(level=my_logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5.5s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[my_logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(log)), my_logging.StreamHandler()])

my_logging.warning('Watch out!')
my_logging.info('info test!')
```

Output of the above code is **Nothing**.

**Now, let's upgrade the package, `abseil`.**

```
!pip install --upgrade absl-py
```

Let's check what is the version of `abseil` now:

```
!pip show absl-py
```

Output of the above command is

```
Name: absl-py
Version: 0.9.0
```

Now, if we execute the code,

```
import logging as my_logging
from datetime import datetime
from keras.models import load_model

time_f = datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%Y_%H%M')
save_path = 'sample_data'
log = save_path+"automation_log_" + time_f + ".log"
my_logging.basicConfig(level=my_logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5.5s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[my_logging.FileHandler("{0}".format(log)), my_logging.StreamHandler()])

my_logging.warning('Watch out!')
my_logging.info('info test!')
```

Output is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
14/05/2020 08:03:00 [WARNI] Watch out!
14/05/2020 08:03:00 [INFO ] info test!
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!